# How to search for a string in part of text?

Tags: python

I am trying to search multiple text files for the text "1-2","2-3","3-H" which occur in the last field of the lines of text that start with "play".

An example of the text file is show below

```
id,ARI201803290
version,2
info,visteam,COL
info,hometeam,ARI
info,site,PHO01
play,1,0,lemad001,22,CFBBX,HR/78/F
play,1,0,arenn001,20,BBX,S7/L+
play,1,0,stort001,12,SBCFC,K
play,1,0,gonzc001,02,SS>S,K
play,1,1,perad001,32,BTBBCX,S9/G
play,1,1,polla001,02,CSX,S7/L+.1-2
play,1,1,goldp001,32,SBFBBB,W.2-3;1-2
play,1,1,lambj001,00,X,D9/F+.3-H;2-H;1-3
play,1,1,avila001,31,BC*BBX,31/G.3-H;2-3
play,2,0,grayj003,12,CC*BS,K
play,2,1,dysoj001,31,BBCBX,43/G
play,2,1,corbp001,31,CBBBX,43/G
play,4,1,avila001,02,SC1>X,S8/L.1-2
```

For the text file above, I would like the output to be '4' since there are 4 occurrences of "1-2","2-3" and "3-H" in total.

The code I have got so far is below, however I'm not sure where to start with writing a line of code to do this function.

```
import os

input_folder = 'files'  # path of folder containing the multiple text files

# create a list with file names 
data_files = [os.path.join(input_folder, file) for file in     
os.listdir(input_folder)]

# open csv file for writing
csv = open('myoutput.csv', 'w')  
def write_to_csv(line):
    print(line)
    csv.write(line)


j=0 # initialise as 0
count_of_plate_appearances=0 # initialise as 0


for file in data_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:  # use context manager to open files
        for line in f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            i=0      
            while i < len(lines):
                temp_array = lines[i].rstrip().split(",")
                if temp_array[0] == "id":
                    j=0
                    count_of_plate_appearances=0
                    game_id = temp_array[1]
                    awayteam = lines[i+2].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    hometeam = lines[i+3].rstrip().split(",")[2]
                    date = lines[i+5].rstrip().split(",")[2]

                    for j in range(i+46,i+120,1): #only check for plate appearances this when temp_array[0] == "id"
                        temp_array2 = lines[j].rstrip().split(",") #create new array to check for plate apperances
                        if temp_array2[0] == "play" and temp_array2[2] == "1": # plate apperance occurs when these are true

count_of_plate_appearances=count_of_plate_appearances+1
                    #print(count_of_plate_appearances)
                    output_for_csv2=(game_id,date,hometeam, awayteam,str(count_of_plate_appearances))
                    print(output_for_csv2)
                    csv.write(','.join(output_for_csv2) + '\n')                     
                    i=i+1

                else:
                    i=i+1

                    j=0
                    count_of_plate_appearances=0
                #quit()


csv.close()
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex`, I put your text in a file called `file.txt`.

```
import re
a = ['1-2', '2-3', '3-H'] # What you want to count
find_this = re.compile('|'.join(a)) # Make search string
count = 0
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        count += len(find_this.findall(line)) # Each findall returns the list of things found
print(count) # 7
```

or a shorter solution: (Credit to wjandrea for hinting the use of a generator)

```
import re
a = ['1-2', '2-3', '3-H'] # What you want to count
find_this = re.compile('|'.join(a)) # Make search string
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = sum(len(find_this.findall(line)) for line in f)
print(count) # 7
```

Comment: You could simplify with a generator expression: `count = len(find_this.findall(line) for line in f)`

Comment: @wjandrea thanks though `len` doesn't take a generator (but I can use `sum` instead), so thanks for the tip :)